# Choosing columns from a matrix (tensor actually) in TF and scattering back zeros?

Tags: tensorflow

Assume that I have a Tensor `A` of dimension `[None, N, ...]` and I want to choose the columns `[c1, ..., ck]` from it, where each `ci` is a constant that is known in advance.

I would want to generate a tensor `B` of shape `[None, N, ...]`, such that

```
B[i, j, ...] == A[i, j, ...] if j in [c1, ..., ck]
```

and otherwise

```
B[i, j, ...] == 0 if j not in [c1, ..., ck]
```

How can I do this? I assume that `tf.scatter_nd` could be used, but I can't figure out exactly the `indices` work for high-dimensional tensors.

Comment: "I want to choose the columns `[c1, ..., ck]` from it". - Maybe "columns" is not the most appropriate term to use here, given that you're not dealing with matrices, but, in general, tensors. So, what exactly does `[c1, ..., ck]` represent? You probably mean "dimension". So, `cj` (in `[c1, ..., ck]`) is the dimension `j` of the tensor?

Comment: Not really. Columns would refer to the second dimension. I want to choose B[:,[c1, ..., ck], ...] and then scatter that back to agree with the shape of A, so that B agrees with A for those particular indices in the second dimension. For any other index in the second dimension, all elements are zero.